# Why do you need to Unit test basic SQL functionality?

Tags: sql, unit-testing, junit

I have seen people create Junit tests that tests basic SQL functionality like:

Insert 1 row into a table

Select that a variable from that row is retrieved correctly.

I do not understand why it is necessary to test "if SQL works".

The path that you usually go through to develop SQL is that you write it against a database with data and check if the results are what you expected. You can go further and verify your SQL against more data until you are satisfied that you have covered enough edge cases.

Isn't this level of testing thorough enough? How can these basic Junit tests compare to this method?

Comment: Unit testing can be a religious battle sometimes.  Some insist on chasing the 100% code coverage goal, even at the expense of business costs.  Some components don't contain any meaningful logic and the value of testing them is *very low* compared to other things the programmer could be doing.  On the other hand, I've certainly found myself on projects where there was *tons* of downtime and I figured, eh, why the heck not?

Comment: I would call it rather an integration test if a database is involved. If you have a unit test you would rather test that running a simple query creates the right calls on the database driver.

Answer (score 0):

That does seem a little intense,

In general I think it can be reasonable to test simple thats to ensure that if they are made more complicated, care is taken to not break other stuff. Writing tests is considered a form of documentation. I expect this call to only bring back one line of SQL I requested. If someone tries to put some logic in there, hopefully the unit test will break and they will consider what they are doing is potentially breaking other code that depends on it.

Comment: Apparently, I am required to test if anyone makes any changes to the sql or the underlying table. So test every column is returned back from the query, test foreign key constraints, test ids are generated as expected.